# How to avoid full CPU utilisation, or terminate, while InternetOpenURL is trying (and failing) to connect?

Tags: winapi, cpu-usage, wininet

I have a fairly simple application which downloads files in a thread.  This thread uses the [WinINet APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385483%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and begins like so:

```
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(strUserAgent.c_str(), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    DWORD dwFlags = INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI | INTERNET_FLAG_HYPERLINK | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD;
    HINTERNET hUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hInternet, m_strURL.c_str(), L"", 0, dwFlags, NULL);
```

However, if there is no internet connection, or the remote host is down, [`InternetOpenUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will take a long time to time out and complete.  While it is doing this - that is, only in the situation that it can't connect to the remote host - it will use between 80-100% of one CPU until it finally returns.  This can often continue for a minute or so, because of the timeout delay setting.  On one system, *in spite of the timeout settings* (noted below), this has continued for up to ten minutes.

How do I:

- Avoid such massive CPU usage when it's just trying to connect?
- Signal the thread to terminate if I want to shut down the app?  Normally a timeout is fine, but if the app needs to close then it will wait on this thread to finish, which is spending lots of CPU doing very little inside `InternetOpenUrl`.

---

[Aside: Current timeout settings on my system, as revealed by InternetQueryOption:

- `INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`: 60s
- `INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT`: 30s
- `INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT`: 30s

Changing these would decrease the time before the method gave up and returned and so decrease the time spent using so much CPU, but might affect connecting - after all, the timeouts are there for a reason.  This app can be used in odd connection situations, such as on board ship, where connecting could potentially be over satellite with high latency and take longer than a standard desktop internet connection.  I do not know what reasonable timeouts would be. Also, there has to be a better method to avoid the CPU usage and terminate more quickly than simply shortening the timeouts.]

Comment: This is weird. Do you experience this CPU clogging issue on many computers or is it only on yours? I don't expect such behaviour from WinInet.

Comment: It's on two at least: Windows 7 on a WMWare Fusion machine (mine - it only spikes to 80% on mine though) and Windows XP (I think) on a second machine (a QA staff member's.)

Comment: Have you tried to use WinInet in asynchronous mode?

Comment: @Sergius: no, I haven't. In fact I'd forgotten it had an async mode. Some googling turned up [an interesting article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/asyncwininet.aspx) which specifically mentions terminating.  I think you should add this as an answer!

Comment: I don't see any CPU usage in this scenario and an error is returned almost immediately.  Perhaps it is a hardware or driver issue.

Comment: Any reason to not use WinHTTP instead of WinInet? It's a successor, with syntax so much similar, and possibly free from the issue.

Comment: @Luke: except it happens on (now) three different computers, on two OSes, on two networks.

Comment: @Roman: Looks like WinHTTP is only XP+, is that right?  I need to support Win2K too.

Comment: @David: MSDN says it's Windows 2000 Professional with SP3 and from what I remember we did not have issues with supporting Win 2K after we switched to WinHTTP. They are pretty much the same, syntax is close (I even had a thin wrapper which converted WinHTTP calls into WinInet calls with a single #define). All in all, WinHTTP gave less troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WinInet in [asynchronous mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383892). Not sure whether it solves CPU utilization issue but termination can be handled properly.

Comment: Reading the documentation, this seems like the safest option for terminating to me.  I don't have time to try it before the bounty expires, but it sounds good, so have yourself some points!

Comment: @David, asynchronous mode won't help in your case though its the recommended way of using WinINet library. In your case InternetOpenUrl is taking time, so in asynchronous mode also you wont be able to terminate the function unless you close the session handle.

Comment: @Vishal, InternetOpenUrl shouldn't block in asynchronous mode.

Comment: @Sergius, agree InternetOpenUrl wont block in async mode, but it need to complete and return the handle to do any processing on that handle. which in terms is no better putting it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can close the session handle returned from InternetOpen with InternetCloseHandle.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384350(v=VS.85).aspx it will unblock any pending operation on that handle.

So basically if you keep InternetOpenUrl in a separate thread, you can still close the session handle from the parent thread(a seperate thread is not required if you are using it in async mode). You can set a status callback function for any resource cleanup.

If you want to set a different timeout, use InternetSetOption.

PS: Its been a while I've done anything with WinINet library, so I cannot guarantee that the above method will work.

Comment: Interesting - so I'd call InternetOpenUrl but pass the handle it returns to the main thread, which can close it?

Comment: What I said is you can keep InternetOpenUrl in a separate thread and when you want to stop the operation close the HINTERNET handle that you supplied as the first argument in the main thread.