# Decrease InternetOpenUrl timeout?

Tags: delphi, wininet, delphi-xe7

This function checks whether an URL can be reached or not:

```
uses wininet, System.Types,

...

function CheckUrl(url: string): boolean;
var
  hSession, hfile, hRequest: hInternet;
  dwindex, dwcodelen: dword;
  dwcode: array [1 .. 20] of char;
  res: pchar;
begin
  if pos('http://', lowercase(url)) = 0 then
    url := 'http://' + url;
  Result := false;
  hSession := InternetOpen('InetURL:/1.0', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
    nil, nil, 0);
  if assigned(hSession) then
  begin
    hfile := InternetOpenUrl(hSession, pchar(url), nil, 0,
      INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    dwindex := 0;
    dwcodelen := 10;
    HttpQueryInfo(hfile, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, @dwcode, dwcodelen, dwindex);
    res := pchar(@dwcode);
    Result := (res = '200') or (res = '302');
    if assigned(hfile) then
      InternetCloseHandle(hfile);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;
```

However, when there is no Internet connection, the function returns only after 21 seconds. So how can I restrict the timeout to 2 seconds?

Here is a test program:

```
program CheckURLTest;

{.$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{.$R *.res}

uses
  CodeSiteLogging,
  wininet,
  System.Types,
  System.SysUtils;

function CheckUrl(url: string): boolean;
var
  hSession, hfile, hRequest: hInternet;
  dwindex, dwcodelen: dword;
  dwcode: array [1 .. 20] of char;
  res: pchar;
begin
  if pos('http://', lowercase(url)) = 0 then
    url := 'http://' + url;
  Result := false;
  hSession := InternetOpen('InetURL:/1.0', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
    nil, nil, 0);
  if assigned(hSession) then
  begin
    hfile := InternetOpenUrl(hSession, pchar(url), nil, 0,
      INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    dwindex := 0;
    dwcodelen := 10;
    HttpQueryInfo(hfile, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, @dwcode, dwcodelen, dwindex);
    res := pchar(@dwcode);
    Result := (res = '200') or (res = '302');
    if assigned(hfile) then
      InternetCloseHandle(hfile);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;

var
  TestURL: string;

begin
  try
    TestURL := 'http://www.google.com';

    CodeSite.Send('VOR CheckUrl');
    if CheckUrl(TestURL) then
      CodeSite.Send(TestURL + ' exists!')
    else
      CodeSite.Send(TestURL + ' does NOT exist!');

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `InternetSetOption` and set the <strike>receive</strike> connect timeout (`INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`). (Corrected to use `CONNECT` instead of `RECEIVE`, thanks to a comment from @JoshKelley.)

```
var
  dwTimeOut: DWORD;


dwTimeOut := 2000; // Timeout in milliseconds
InternetSetOption(hSession, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 
                  @dwTimeOut, SizeOf(dwTimeOut));
```

Comment: Ken, with this one the timeout was over a minute, then 14 seconds, then 14 seconds (router cable detached).

Comment: @user1580348: So adjust the timeout value in `dwTimeOut`. I don't have your setup to test with, and can't do it from this machine. I left a comment in the code to explain what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says the value should be.

Comment: Even with `INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` the function again returned only after one minute. I've tried to put it before or after `hfile := InternetOpenUrl` - the timeout was always 14 - 18 seconds. The documentation says `milliseconds`, and there's only one IP address here.

Comment: It has to be before the call to `InternetOpenURL`, because after would do you no good. :-) As I said, I answered the question you asked, which is how to change the timeout. I can't debug it on your network connection, because I have no access to your network connection.

Comment: Your solution is correct. I have now set the timeout to `500` and I wonder why `InternetOpenUrl` returns still only after 14 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [InternetSetOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set `INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`, or use [async mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7534346/25507) so that you have full control over timeouts.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I came only to `InternetSetOption(hfile, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, ???)`. Could you please help me with the other parameters?

Comment: @user1580348 - [@Ken White's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28774415/25507) has a complete example (although he uses `INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT` - I'd have to test to see if, in practice, you need that or `INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` or both).

Comment: His answer arrived here after my comment.

Comment: @Josh: You're correct; it should be CONNECT and not RECEIVE. I'll correct (with proper attribution). I've already upvoted your answer, which was posted while I was putting mine together.

Comment: Is this the correct method to use async mode in this case?: `hSession := InternetOpen('InetURL:/1.0', INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC, nil, nil, 0);`

Comment: Strange: When I use `hSession := InternetOpen('InetURL:/1.0', INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC, nil, nil, 0);` then the function CheckURL always returns very fast and always returns False (when I am connected to the Internet).

Comment: @user1580348 - Async mode is radically different. It always returns immediately, before the operation completes, and you need to set a callback to receive notification of when the operation completes.  See MSDN for more details and example code.